# How do I change a const value when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, event-listener

Can somebody help me replace the console.log lines with something that will help me change the player.choice value based on which button is clicked?

```js
const player = {
  currentChoice: null
}
const computer = {
  currentChoice: null
}



const choices = ["Lapis", "Papyrus", "Scalpellus"];

document.querySelector('#Lapis').onclick = setLapis
document.querySelector('#Papyrus').onclick = setPapyrus
document.querySelector('#Scalpellus').onclick = setScalpellus;

function setLapis(){
  console.log("Lapis");
}
function setPapyrus(){
  console.log("Papyrus");
}
function setScalpellus(){
  console.log("Scalpellus");
}

player.currentChoice = choices[0];
```

```html
<button id="Lapis">Lapis</button>
<button id="Papyrus">Papyrus</button>
<button id="Scalpellus">Scalpellus</button>
```

Comment: player.currentChoice = "Lapis";

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 1):

```js
const player = {
  currentChoice: null
}
const computer = {
  currentChoice: null
}



const choices = ["Lapis", "Papyrus", "Scalpellus"];

document.querySelector('#Lapis').onclick = setLapis
document.querySelector('#Papyrus').onclick = setPapyrus
document.querySelector('#Scalpellus').onclick = setScalpellus;

function setLapis(){
  player.currentChoice = choices[0];
  console.log(player.currentChoice);
}
function setPapyrus(){
  player.currentChoice = choices[1];
  console.log(player.currentChoice);
}
function setScalpellus(){
  player.currentChoice = choices[2];
  console.log(player.currentChoice);
}
```

```html
<button id="Lapis">Lapis</button>
<button id="Papyrus">Papyrus</button>
<button id="Scalpellus">Scalpellus</button>
```